# Ошибка при запуске mongoDB на Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ввожу:

```
$ sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Получаю:

> 2018-11-09T17:45:04.803+0300 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

Затем мне сказали ввести это:

```
sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --sslDisabledProtocols='none'
```

Снова получаю:

> BadValue: need to enable SSL via the sslMode flag when using SSL configuration parameters 
>   try 'mongod --help' for more information

Не могу найти нигде правильного решения, в node пока новичок.

Помогите пожалуйста, что нужно делать?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: В итоге проблему решил? Если да, поделись пожалуйста. Тоже самое у меня, но только на Windows